# Images covering text on mobile devices

Tags: css, image, mobile, text, cover

I'm trying to get this site working for mobile devices: http://whitehallrow.com/

I decided to remove the blue ribbons and corresponding photos for mobile, as they weren't being displayed well. So I made new images that combine the two elements for mobile. But when I view the page on my Blackberry, the pictures cover a large percentage of the text on the page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into CSS @media only.

Example:

**Normal screen:**

```
#div {
   properties for normal screen;
}
```

**Mobile**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #div {
  properties for mobile device here;
  }
}
```

See a more in depth look here: [@media only screen](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: I've been using media queries, that's how I've been displaying certain elements of the page only on mobile. I'm wondering if there's a simple CSS trick that can keep the pictures from covering text?

Comment: You may be able to make it display: block in the media query to automatically drop it beneath the previous div.